# showing horizontal scroll bar flutter

Tags: flutter, paginateddatatable

I want to always show the scroll bar below the datatable for the web version. But it's showing this error message:

> The Scrollbar's ScrollController has no ScrollPosition attached.

and the scroll bar doesn't work.

```
Scrollbar(
  isAlwaysShown: true,
  controller: ScrollController(),
  thickness: 10,
  child: PaginatedDataTable(
      showCheckboxColumn: false,
      columns: generateColumns(),
      source: generateDataSources(),
      rowsPerPage: count.toInt()),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well try to remove the controller then ?
`controller: ScrollController()`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `controller: ScrollController(),` line or comment it out. and the exception should be cleared. That is how I fixed mine.

Comment: Your answer appear to be a duplicate of another answer. Please review any previous answers before answering a question on the site to be sure that you are not needlessly repeating information.